# YITH Woocommerce Request A Quote Premium

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, woocommerce, quote

I am using WordPress 5.2 with the plugin [YITH Woocommerce Request A Quote Premium](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote/).

Whenever I hit “Send Your Request” the page refreshes and nothing happens. No email is sent and when I enabled debug in wp-config I get this:

```
Notice: is_main_query was called incorrectly. In pre_get_posts, use the WP_Query->is_main_query() method,

Notice: id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The page after hitting save is just blanked ?

Comment: no it is a form that must be completed and after sending the page remains in charge and the form does not send

Comment: Can you share the URL with me?

Comment: @sa1995, with debug enabled it should also give you the line number of the problem code. If it is in the plugin, I would contact the authors of that plugin because it isn't open source. If it is elsewhere, look at this post which shows how to change the property access to a method call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221578/notice-is-main-query-was-called-incorrectly

Comment: here is what i have when i active debug: